# Memcache getVersion is not the same as phpinfo

Tags: php, memcached

Here is the code:

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
$result = $memcache->get("TEST");
if ($result)
{
  echo $result;
}
else
{
  echo "TEST key not found, adding key";
  if (!$memcache->set("TEST", "Memcache key found. Memcache is working."))
  {
    echo "could not set memcache key";
  }
}
echo "Memcache version: ";
var_dump($memcache->getVersion());
```

This part results in:

1.2.6

However, the phpinfo says it is 2.2.5:
[image]

When I run the command `memcached -h` directly on the server, I get 1.2.6

Why is there a difference in version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$memcache->getVersion()` returns the version of the server (according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.getversion.php)), while `phpinfo()` shows the version of the memcache PHP extension.

Comment: Thank you. How can I get the version of the memcache PHP extension?

Comment: Found it: phpversion("memcache")